# Magento 1: New server / There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento-1.9

I've moved a magento installation to a new server and thought i'd covered everything:

http://www.gep.co.uk/store/

But i'm getting the error. I think the report in var/report is:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:56:"Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists";i:1;s:1774:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/Mage.php(563): Mage::register('_resource_helpe...', false)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(534): Mage::getResourceHelper('core')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_prepareSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Website/Collection.php(137): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(729): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website_Collection->load()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(634): Varien_Data_Collection->getItemById('0')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/httpdocs/gep/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:56:"/store/index.php/cd-s/southern-empire/images/favicon.ico";s:11:"script_name";s:16:"/store/index.php";}
```

Comment: try after clear session and cache.

Comment: I deleted the files in: var/cache and var/session but it didn't work. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: compiler is enabled in your source?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: edit this file `{your store root}/includes/config.php` and check code exist with this  `#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');` or `define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');`

Comment: I've located the PHP file and it contains that line but am I supposed to modify it? Sorry, I just can't get my head around what i'm supposed to do

Comment: did you found this `#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');`?

Comment: Yes, I found that line in config.php

Comment: I'm just wondering. When I imported the Database, should I have unchecked 'Enable foreign key checks'? or would that not have made any difference?

Comment: it is not the issue. we should not unchecked 'Enable foreign key checks' that.